# GMSMapView not allowing peek and pop (3D Touch)

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

I have a Google Maps `GMSMapView` with a custom callout that is shown. I have setup the previewing context:

```
self.previewingContext = [self registerForPreviewingWithDelegate:self sourceView:self.view];
```

As well as the delegate method `previewingContext:viewControllerForLocation:`.

When using the iOS `MKMapView` I can hard press anywhere on the map and it will call the delegate method.

However, when using `GMSMapView` hard pressing on the mapView does NOT call the delegate method.

Is there a reason why `GMSMapView` wouldn't be getting those hard press events and calling the delegate?

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and it fix the issue:

```
self.googleMapView.settings.consumesGesturesInView = NO;
```